# adding cell of a table in itext

Tags: java, itext

why is the cell containing paragraph p not being added to table?

```
package iText;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class NewMain1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document document = new Document();

        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\om\\Desktop\\pdf\\2.pdf"));

            document.open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.
             Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 22, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("xyz", font);
        table.addCell("abc");    
        table.addCell(p);

            table.addCell("cef");
            table.addCell("ghi");
           // table.completeRow();
            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));

            table.addCell(cell1);
            table.addCell(cell2);
            table.addCell(cell3);
cell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            document.add(table);

            document.close();
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

p.s I'm a newbie at this itext. It would be great if anyone could explain me how to generate pdf forms through itext. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Look here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=142) or try google.

Comment: @Jens I've seen those examples, but I'm not able to find out my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're create a white font and drawing it on a canvas that is usually displayed as white. It is there, you just can't see it. Try changing the color to something else like `BaseColor.BLACK`.

**EDIT**

To answer the question in your comment, one of the overloads for the [`Document`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/Document.java#l192) constructor takes a rectangle that defines the default size for pages. iText has a helper class called [`PageSize`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/PageSize.java) that defines many common pages but you are free to use any dimension from `3 x 3` up to `14,400 x 14,400`. For instance, you could say `new Document(PageSize.LETTER)` or `new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(612, 702))`.

Once you know that, you've got your maximum `x` and `y` and unless you do something really weird your minimum `x` and `y` are both zero. With PDFs, the bottom left corner is the origin point and thus `0 x 0`.

Comment: thanx :)
umm can you please tell me 1 more thing.. If I've to draw a canvas or rectangle or place image or anything on specific x and y coordinates then how would I know these coordinates?